# PHP Add double quotes before and after numbers in json string

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm trying to add double quotes to numbers in a json string. For example:

`{"id":1, "result": 288230376201306378}`

Should be:

`{"id":1, "result": "288230376201306378"}`

How do I achieve this? I read somewhere that I'm supposed to use regular expressions. Unfortunately, I'm kinda new to that.

Also, I would be very grateful if you could point me to some online resources which would help me understand regex.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: `json_encode(response)` in PHP

Comment: How you are creating your response?

Comment: @Manwal I am not creating the response in my code. I'm implementing an API using a text-based protocol, which returns the response in json format.

Comment: @Tushar: you can't use `json_decode/encode` in this case, PHP will not add itself quotes around numeric values and will change large numbers to scientific notation.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's what I'm saying, use `json_encode` when sending response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {"id":1, "result": 288230376201306378}

The `id` is also a number, if you want to modify it too, use :

```
$myJsonString = '{"id":1, "result": 288230376201306378}';

$myNewJsonString = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)":\s*(\d+)/', '"\1": "\2"', $myJsonString);
```

If you only want to modify the `result` use :

```
$myJsonString = '{"id":1, "result": 288230376201306378}';

$myNewJsonString = preg_replace('/"result"\s*:\s*(\d+)/', '"result": "\1"', $myJsonString);
```

For your question about regex, there are many tutorials on internet. I personally use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test my regex in real time (there is also a "quick reference", which summarize the main tokens used in regex).

---

Since regex are not an optimal solution in this case, you can cast your numbers into string before adding them to your array `(string)$myNumber`. The numbers will be considered as strings and quotes will be added when you `json_encode` the whole data.

Comment: Even if it works for the given example, it's a bit dangerous because you don't know if you are or not between quotes, example: `{"mykey": "abcd: 123, defg: 456"}`

Comment: I modified the first regex to make it safer and added a warning about regex.