# PHP Add double quotes before and after variable in json string

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm trying to add double quotes to Every Variable like `file:` and `label:` in a json string. For example:

```
{file:"File_Name.mp3"},{file:"File_Name.mp4",label:"720"},{file:"File_Name.mp4",label:"360"}
```

Should be:

```
{"file":"File_Name.mp3"},{"file":"File_Name.mp4","label":"720"},{"file":"File_Name.mp4","label":"360"}
```

How can i do this? I read a article of stackoverflow [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564078/php-add-double-quotes-before-and-after-numbers-in-json-string) but my problem not solved with this. I'm supposed to use regular expressions. Unfortunately, but i am new.

and i need to get `file name` if label is 360 so what will be the php code give the filename as i point-out in php.

Thanks.

Comment: Your input is not valid [JSON](http://json.org). How do you get it?

Comment: @axiac I think it's just part of JSON. So it could be valid.

Comment: @revo Even if surrounded by `[` and `]` to become an array, it is still not valid because JSON always encodes the object keys as strings (using double quotes).

Comment: @axiac and that's why OP asks for it?!

Comment: 'Unfortunately, but i am new' - that's fine as people will help.  So what have you found so far, have you managed to learn anything about regular expressions and what have you tried.

Comment: Why are you doing this? I don't understand. The quotes are not neccessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if you're new to all this, maybe regular expressions aren't the best answer.

You can also use a simple `str_replace` function ([doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php)) like this :

`str_replace(array('file:', 'label:'),array('"file":', '"label":'),$your_json_string);`

To exploit the json in php, you'll need to decode it using `json_decode`, and use a loop to check the label values (I advise a `foreach` loop).

Comment: but when i do this i didn't get any result ...!
`$myNewJsonString = str_replace(array('file:', 'label:'),array('"file":', '"label":'),$get_sourceArray);
 $someArray = json_decode($myNewJsonString, true);
 
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r ($someArray);
 echo '</pre>';
 exit;`

Comment: Since "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded", maybe there's still some formating error in your JSON.

`$myNewJsonString = str_replace(array('file:', 'label:'),array('"file":', '"label":'),$get_sourceArray); 
    
echo $myNewJsonString;
    
$someArray = json_decode($myNewJsonString, true);
    
print_r ($someArray);`
Try this to see what's happening, and if you don't see any problems in the JSON string, maybe post a new question with these infos.