# mySQL syntax issue in PDO script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This PDO script seems to be written correctly, but I keep receiving a syntax error with no json array being generated.

```
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `person`,
       sum( `stat` = "Ready" ) as Num1
        from `Table1`
        WHERE `code` = :code AND
        (`stat` = "Ready")
        group by `person`
        Order by `Num1` DESC ');

  $stmt->execute([
      'code' => $_POST['code']
      ]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($row);
```

**This is the error message I get:**

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]
```

Comment: add  the complete error message  . (not only first part)

Comment: stat = "Ready" or status = "Ready" (different in select and where)?

Comment: Try to change `status` = "Ready" in `status` = 'Ready' (single quote)

Comment: @scaisEdge Is it correct to do, `$stmt = $pdo->query` for the query and then `$stmt->execute` ?

Comment: @scaisEdge The entire error message I get is: `Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 ' `

Comment: i have post and answer  hope is useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remember that named  param require `:` so `:code`  and not `code`  in execute array key

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `person`,
       sum( `stat` = "Ready" ) as Num1
        from `Table1`
        WHERE `code` = :code AND
        (`stat` = "Ready")
        group by `person`
        Order by `Num1` DESC ');

  $stmt->execute([
      ':code' => $_POST['code']
      ]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and for json  you can

```
  $myJson = json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, really quick question, how can make all values in the json array come out as strings? Is there any criteria I can put at the end of the PDO?

Comment: I do json_encode($row); but even if my SELECT query selects numbers I want them to have double quotes around them. **Example:** `" 2 "` not  `2`

Comment: why downvote  ???' ..  json  is standard  .. so the number have not double quote  ..  only the string have double quote

Comment: Can I force the numbers to also be double quote?

Comment: is not JSON  ..  is not a valid JSON format  ..  anyway you could  check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564078/php-add-double-quotes-before-and-after-numbers-in-json-string